# Weird Behaviour in R if else Statement

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm quit new to R programming. While I was trying to write my first if else statement I came across a weird behaviour which I don't understand.

When I run below code:

```
x = 4;
y=4;
        if (x==y) {
      print('they are equal');
    } else {
      print('they are not equal');
    }
```

I get no error and I get the expected output. However when I change the indentation of the same exact code as below:

```
if(x==y){print('they are equal');}
else{print('they are not equal');}
```

I get an error message saying that 'Error: unexpected 'else' in "else"'.

So does this means that R is an indentation sensitive language like Python?

Comment: From the documentation: `Note that it is a common mistake to forget to put braces ({ .. }) around your statements, e.g., after if(..) or for(....). In particular, you should not have a newline between } and else to avoid a syntax error in entering a if ... else construct at the keyboard or via source. `

Answer (score 2):

To my limited experience, in **R** syntex, `else` statement should start from the same line where `if` statement ends. Otherwise, it won't work. And **R** is **NOT** indenting sensitive. For example,

**This will work**

```
if(x==y){print('they are equal')
  } else
    {print('they are not equal')}  



[1] "they are equal"
```

**Even this will work**

```
if(x==y){print('they are equal')} else
{print('they are not equal')}  

[1] "they are equal"
```

**This will also work**

```
if(x==y){print('they are equal')} else {print('they are not equal')}  

[1] "they are equal"
```

But the code you have written doesn't work because `else` statement doesn't start from the same line where `if` statement ends. Another example would be,

**This won't work**

```
if(x==y){print('they are equal')} 
else {
  print('they are not equal')}
```

Also, you don't need the semi-colons.

Comment: Remove the semi-colons, please. R is not C, in R the semi-colon marks the end of an instruction so `print('they are not equal');` is in fact ***two*** instructions: `print('they are not equal'); NULL` the print and the `NULL` instruction.

Comment: @RuiBarradas: I agree, semi-colons are not needed. Edited my answer.